# What is correct new line in XML received in server response

Tags: xml

I'm receiving an XML formatted response from a server in which CRLF in strings is represented as raw `0x0d,0x0a` sequence (two chars). Like on a screen shot below (*added specially for people who keep posting and +1'ing comments that line breakes between tags dont matter*)

[image]

According to [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends),

> XML parsed entities are often stored in computer files which, for
>   editing convenience, are organized into lines. These lines are
>   typically separated by some combination of the characters CARRIAGE
>   RETURN (#xD) and LINE FEED (#xA).
>
> To simplify the tasks of applications, the XML processor must behave
>   as if it normalized all line breaks in external parsed entities
>   (including the document entity) on input, before parsing, by
>   translating both the two-character sequence #xD #xA and any #xD that
>   is not followed by #xA to a single #xA character.

My question is: what should server response contain: raw `0x0a` ASCII character or its HTML-encoded version `&#10;`

Does it depend on MIME type in server response header? Currently it sends `application/xml`, thus I tend to believe it should be a raw `0x0a` char. Am I right?

Comment: XML doesn't required CRLF between tags.  Only needed in strings.  See following webpage for XML special characters (CRLF) isn't one of them.

Comment: Not between tags, in strings

Comment: XML doesn't required CRLF between tags. Only needed in strings. See following webpage for XML special characters (CRLF) isn't one of them : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

> XML parsed entities are often stored in computer files which, for editing convenience, are organized into lines. These lines are typically separated by some combination of the characters carriage-return (#xD) and line-feed (#xA).
>   To simplify the tasks of applications, wherever an external parsed entity or the literal entity value of an internal parsed entity contains either the literal two-character sequence "#xD#xA" or a standalone literal #xD, an XML processor must pass to the application the single character #xA. (This behavior can conveniently be produced by normalizing all line breaks to #xA on input, before parsing.)

-- From the XML Recommendation. Unstated here: an XML serializer may write out newlines in either of those forms. Typically, unless instructed otherwise, it will use whichever representation is native for the operating system it is running in.